# How do I use the Ant exec task to run piped commands?

Tags: shell, ant, pipe

I'm trying to run the following command using the 'exec' task in Ant:

```
ls -l /foo/bar | wc -l
```

Currently, I have my exec looking like this:

```
<exec executable="ls" outputproperty="noOfFiles">
    <arg value="-l" />
    <arg value="/foo/bar" />
    <arg value="|" />
    <arg value="wc" />
    <arg value="-l" />
</exec>
```

The 'ls' command looks to be working but it's having a hard time piping the output to 'wc'. Any suggestions?

Comment: it looks like it might be worth it to just write a simple ant task to accomplish this, instead of using exec.

Comment: There already is such a task, called `resourcecount`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you use `sh -c` as Aaron suggests, you can pass the whole pipeline as a single arg, effectively doing:

```
sh -c "ls -l foo/bar | wc -l"
```

If you use separate args, they are consumed by sh, not passed through to ls (hence you see just the current directory).

Note that on my system, `ls -l` includes a total as well as a list of the files found, which means the count shown is one more than the number of files.  So suggest:

```
<exec executable="sh" outputproperty="noOfFiles">
    <arg value="-c" />
    <arg value="ls foo/bar | wc -l" />
</exec>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, this solves the issue I was facing. Thanks Aaron too.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to count the files in a directory, don't use an external shell at all. Use the `resourcecount` task. Fast, compact, portable, and easy to read:

```
<resourcecount property="numfiles">
  <fileset dir="."/>
</resourcecount>
```

And you can of course customize the `fileset` to just include the specific files you need.

(There are actually very few cases where you need to spawn an external shell. Ant's built in I/O redirectors and input/output filter chains can often accomplish the same thing in a portable manner, even if it is sometimes a little verbose.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment JesperE. I will look into resourcecount and replace my current solution with it. Cheers

Comment: The other answer was the answer I was searching for, but +1 for providing the best answer to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You need someone to recognize and build the pipe. Try `sh`:

```
<exec executable="sh" outputproperty="noOfFiles">
    <arg value="-c" />
    <arg value="ls" />
    <arg value="-l" />
    <arg value="/foo/bar" />
    <arg value="|" />
    <arg value="wc" />
    <arg value="-l" />
</exec>
```

Comment: Hi Aaron - It's almost working! It seems to be ignoring the /foo/bar directory and just counting the amount of files in the current directory you are in on bash.

Comment: Try `/bin/ls -1` (one, not i or L) and always use an absolute path.

Comment: `ls -l /foo/bar | wc -l` should all be a single argument to /bin/sh.

Comment: @JesperE: On the command line, I'd agree but not in Java. If you split the arguments, then the path can contain special characters (like spaces) and it will still work.

Comment: You're missing my point. If you want `sh` to execute a shell script, you need to pass the script as *one* argument. Passing "ls" "-l" etc. to `sh` doesn't make sense. If you want to pass a path to `sh` which contains spaces, you need to quote it.